# Connection is open and is not closed in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Hello Friends i am trying to develop a shout box in asp.net but it ends with an error The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open. Can you please help me out what is the problem in my code .

```
Shout.aspx.cs

using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace finalWork
{
    public partial class Shout : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                PopulateTextBox();
            }
        }
        private void PopulateTextBox()
        {
            SqlConnection con = ConnectionManager.GetDatabaseConnection();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string name = string.Empty, message = string.Empty;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                string sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM Message";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                sqlDa.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //get the data stored from the DataTable
                        name = dt.Rows[i]["Username"].ToString();// where Name is the FieldName from database
                        message = dt.Rows[i]["Message"].ToString();
                        sb.AppendFormat("Name:{0}Date Posted:{1}{2}", name + Environment.NewLine
                                               , DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + Environment.NewLine
                                               , message + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    // get the concated and formatted values from string builder and display the result in TextBoxPrintMessage

                    TextBoxPrintMessage.Text = sb.ToString();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
                string msg = "Fetch Error:";
                msg += ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(msg);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        private void AddNewPost(string name, string message)
        {

            SqlConnection con = ConnectionManager.GetDatabaseConnection();
            string sqlStatement = string.Empty;

            sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO Message" +
                           "(Username,Message)" +
                           "VALUES (@Username,@Message)";
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", message);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
                string msg = "Insert Error:";
                msg += ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(msg);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        protected void ButtonPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Check for empty values fieds before inserting the record
            if (TextBoxName.Text != string.Empty && TextBoxMessage.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                //insert new post to database
                AddNewPost(TextBoxName.Text.Trim(), TextBoxMessage.Text.Trim());
                //Populate the TextBox to reflect changes made
                PopulateTextBox();
            }
            else
            {
                //display message if the field was not supplied
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Script",
                "alert('Please supply the required  fields!');", true);
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you are using `con.Close()` in `try` statement as well as in `finally` statement.

Comment: What does `ConnectionManager.GetDatabaseConnection` do exactly (are you creating a new connection object or re-using one)? On what line do you get that error?

Comment: When you use the `SqlDataAdapter.Fill`, you don't have to open the connection explicitly, it is automatically opened and closed. However if you open the connection before calling `Fill`, it will remain open after `Fill`, as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I just manually add it and it works :)

```
 string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
```

Comment: You can actually use

`using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
con.Open();
/*Stuff*/
}`
And do away with con.Close() altogether

Answer (score 0):

Try This way. It will help you.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(youCconnectionString);
connection.Close(); 
connection.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("YourQuery", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
command.Dispose();
```

Comment: And if command.ExecuteNonQuery() throws an error? You have a database connection left open.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse Then you should close the connection before open. Now see the answer i had updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Add comment to following code its already called in finally block of PopulateTextBox() function.

```
//con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove con.Close(); inside Try block as you have used it in finally block.